# Unable to read value from properties file for dependency in SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, activemq-classic

I am studying ActiveMQ and tried to do a basic POC. Now I am trying to improve my code.
I made 3 springboot projects as shown below:

activemq.listener - has the code for consuming messages from queue
activemq.publisher - has code to publish to queue
activemq.demo - has code for a demo app which uses activemq.listener to send messages to queue.

Below is my code of diff projects:

activemq.listener

```
public class EventListener {
        
    @JmsListener(destination = "${queue.name}")
    public void listen(String message) {
        System.out.println(" RECEIVED ::::: " + message);
    }
}
```

application.properties for listener

```
server.port=8082
spring.activemq.broker-url=tcp://localhost:61616
queue.name=alert-event-queue
```

activemq.publisher

```
@Component
public class ProducerController {   

    @Autowired
    JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;
    
    @Value("${queue.name}")
    private String queue;
    
    public void produce(String message) {
        System.out.println("PRODUCER::::" + message);
        jmsTemplate.convertAndSend(queue,message);
    }
}
```

application.properties for producer

```
spring.activemq.broker-url=tcp://localhost:61616
queue.name=alert-event-queue
server.port=8083
```

code for activemq.demo

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan("io.sharma.akash.activemq.producer.api")
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

}


@RestController
public class DemoController {
    
    @Autowired
    ProducerController producer;

    @GetMapping("/test")
    public void test() {        
        producer.produce("Upskill");
    }       
}
```

code snippet from pom.xml of activemq.demo

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.sharma.akash</groupId>
    <artifactId>activemq.producer</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

As can be seen in demo app code I am trying to use publisher project. I want to maintain queue name in publisher project itself and not in demo project but when i try to build demo project i get the below error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'producerController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'queue.name' in value "${queue.name}"
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:405) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1413) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:601) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
```

So I am unable to Autowire the ProducerController as it's unable to read the property here. There is no issue in reading property inside the publisher project but the same is having issue when used in demo project. Please can someone help me identify the mistake i am making.

Comment: If you're doing a POC with ActiveMQ I would urge you to use [ActiveMQ Artemis](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/) as it is the next-generation broker from ActiveMQ and will provide you with a better performing platform for the future of your project.

Comment: Do you have the properties file in the resources file of the demo project?

Comment: what happens when you add this queue.name=alert-event-queue in the application.properties of your Demo project

Comment: Agree with @Andy, you don't necessarily want your properties from included modules being injected automatically into your application context. Additionally you can include a default `@Value("${queue.name:alert-event-queue}")` such that it works without requiring you to specifically add it to your demo application.properties but you can also redefine it by doing so if you need to.